# Thermal reservoir's effect in Thermodynamic system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I understand the straightforward rule of the system being in the macrostate with maximum multiplicity. But I noticed that as soon as we connect that system to a Thermal reservoir, my system will always try to go into a state with lowest energy.

$\quad \text{Boltzmann factor} = e^{-\beta E(s)}   $

It feels contradictory because lowest energy state has 0 entropy.

Comment: There is a macrostate multiplicity factor $g(E)$ that grows very fast with energy, and that factor compensates enough that the actual macrostate that you will be most likely to find the system and thermal reservoir combination to be in, is with some non-zero mean energy in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comments regarding degeneracy:

The Boltzmann factor, $$P_i \sim e^{-E_i/kT}$$ is the probability to find the system in *microstate $i$*, which happens to have energy $E_i$. It is not the same as to find the system in *a microstate with energy $E$*. That probability is
$$
   P(E) \sim \Omega(E) e^{-E/kT} = e^{\ln\Omega - E/kT}
$$
where $\Omega(E)$ is the degeneracy, the number of microstates with energy $E$. The most probable state maximizes the quantity $\ln\Omega - E/kT = - F/kT$, where $F$ is free energy:
$$
   F = E-kT\log\Omega
$$
Therefore, a system in contact with a bath minimizes its *free energy*.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of finding the system in a given microstate is proportional to $e^{-\beta E}$, but that means there is a reasonable chance of finding the system in any state with an within about $k_BT$ of the ground state.

Talking about the entropy of a single microstate, such as the ground state, is either not meaningful or always zero, depending on who you ask. The entropy of the system is entirely due to the uncertainty about which microstate it is actually in. Overall entropy is maximised for the combined system and environment, as there are typically far more ways to configure that energy in the (very large) environment than in the system.

It is also worth noting, as mentioned by @naturallyInconsistent in the comments, that there is a degeneracy factor, counting the number of microststates with a given energy. This means that the probability distribution for the system energy will generally not be a simple exponential decay and may have a maximum at a higher energy than the ground state.

Comment: According to your last paragraph and to @naturallyInconsistent 's comment, I think you should modify your starting paragraph. The effect of the density of states may push the most probable states many $k_BT$ above the ground state.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 It is important to distinguish between a microstate and an energy level, i.e. the collection of all microstates with the same energy. My intention in the first two paragraphs was to talk about the former, as I think that is closer to the root of the OPs confusion. You are correct that the most probable energy level may be far higher the $k_BT$. I will try to clarify my answer